# docker-composer wordpress asks installation whenever I reboot

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, docker-compose

Everything is fine until I reboot my Ubuntu host.
After reboot, the WordPress page shows the fresh installation page.
There are volumes properly mounted on the host's local directory.

I only have set docker.service to restart the Docker service when reboot.
There must be some mistake I am not aware of.

At least, what shall I do if this thing happens again?
I see all the files mounted on my host shows the latest modification time,
so it looks like the data is persistent...

(edited)
I also tried the external voume as @bilal said in the comment, but it didn't make any difference.
So, now I am thinking this may be related to the process while booting up. like, instead of stop&start, it somehow down/up. But I may be wrong.

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  db:
    container_name: $DB_CONTAINER
    image: mariadb:latest
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - wordpress_db_data:/var/lib/mysql:rw
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: 1
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB_NAME
      MYSQL_USER: $DB_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD

  wp:
    container_name: $WP_CONTAINER
    image: wordpress:latest
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cp
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - wordpress_wp_data:/var/www/html:rw
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: $DB_CONTAINER
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: $DB_NAME
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: $DB_USER
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: $WP_TABLE_PREFIX
      VIRTUAL_HOST: $VIRTUAL_HOST
      VIRTUAL_PORT: $VIRTUAL_PORT
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: $VIRTUAL_HOST
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: $LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL
      #LETSENCRYPT_TEST: 'true'

  cp:
    build: composer
    container_name: ${COMPOSER_CONTAINER}
    volumes:
      - wordpress_wp_data:/app/wp-content:rw
    command: composer install

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx_proxy


volumes:
  wordpress_wp_data:
    name: wordpress_wp_data
  wordpress_db_data:
    name: wordpress_db_data
```

Here's my volume list

```
>  docker volume ls
DRIVER    VOLUME NAME
local     wordpress_db_data
local     wordpress_wp_data
```

Here's my docker.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Application Container Engine
Documentation=https://docs.docker.com
After=network-online.target firewalld.service containerd.service
Wants=network-online.target
Requires=docker.socket containerd.service

[Service]
Type=notify
# the default is not to use systemd for cgroups because the delegate issues still
# exists and systemd currently does not support the cgroup feature set required
# for containers run by docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always

# Note that StartLimit* options were moved from "Service" to "Unit" in systemd 229.
# Both the old, and new location are accepted by systemd 229 and up, so using the old location
# to make them work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitBurst=3

# Note that StartLimitInterval was renamed to StartLimitIntervalSec in systemd 230.
# Both the old, and new name are accepted by systemd 230 and up, so using the old name to make
# this option work for either version of systemd.
StartLimitInterval=60s

# Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
# in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity

# Comment TasksMax if your systemd version does not support it.
# Only systemd 226 and above support this option.
TasksMax=infinity

# set delegate yes so that systemd does not reset the cgroups of docker containers
Delegate=yes

# kill only the docker process, not all processes in the cgroup
KillMode=process
OOMScoreAdjust=-500

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use docker volumes for persistent storage what I understand is you mounted dir. See docker volumes for more information.

so your volume section should look like this.

```
volumes:
      - ./wp_data:/var/www/html:rw
      - wp_data:/wp_data{volume you want to persist}
```

Comment: Thanks @Bilal, I also tried that. Created a volume with separate Docker command, and referenced it as you did above. Still the problem happens. :(